# How to make this Haskell function typecheck

Tags: haskell

```hs
data D = A Int Int | B Int Char

instance Show D where
    show (A a b) = show b
    show (B a b) = show b

hehe :: D -> String
hehe d = show u ++ show v
     where (u, v) = show <$> case d of 
            A a b -> (a + 1, b)
            B a b -> (a + 2, b)
```

The idea is that I want to apply a function over a tuple, but it does not type check because the second element of the tuple can either be an `Int` or a `Char`.

Here is the error message:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Char'
    * In the expression: b
      In the expression: (a + 2, b)
      In a case alternative: B a b -> (a + 2, b)
   |
11 |             B a b -> (a + 2, b)
   |
```

I wonder if there is an elegant solution to solve this?

Comment: You can not return `(a+1, b)` and `(a+2, b)` in the same function, since `b` is for the first match an `Int` whereas for the second it is a `Char`.

Comment: Why are you nesting `show` anyway? That'll just lead to redundant, escaped quotation marks. And, you're aware that fmapping over a tuple does _not_ apply the function to all tuple elements, right?

Comment: Yes, I know fmapping over a tuple only applies to the last element. What I am trying to do here is instead of having to write show twice for each case, we only have to do it once. Just asking if it is possible to do this elegantly

Answer (score 5):

You can just push the show into the case:

```hs
hehe :: D -> String
hehe d = show u ++ show v
     where (u, v) = case d of 
            A a b -> (a + 1, show b)
            B a b -> (a + 2, show b)
```

If you really, really want to delay the show then you can use the `ExistentialQuantification` language extension:

```
data SomeShow = forall a. Show a => SomeShow a

hehe :: D -> String
hehe d = show u ++ show v
     where (u, v) = (\(SomeShow x) -> show x) <$> case d of 
            A a b -> (a + 1, SomeShow b)
            B a b -> (a + 2, SomeShow b)
```

That is not worth it in this case.